# How to package GHC Stage-1 compiler

Tags: ghc

Is there a way to package GHC Stage1 compiler?
I haven't built Stage2 etc. since I am only interested in cross-compiling so `make install` would not help here I assume.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was able to make a docker container for GHC cross compiler (which is Stage1).
The detailed steps are in the docker file.

https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/alexeyraga/ghc-docker-cross-arm/